# How to get element properties in MAUI project from MAUI BlazorWebview?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I have MAUI Blazor App where I use some components inside BlazorWebView. How can I access their properties in MAUI project?
I need to get element distance from top in MauiProject/Platforms/Android/SomeClass.cs.

When I use Activity.CurrentFocus, it returns WebView, not focused element inside of it.
Can I use javascript here and invoke function?

Comment: *When I use Activity.CurrentFocus, it returns WebView,* For MAUI, when the program runs on a specific platform(Android/iOS/Windows), it will use the platform's own controls(Android.Webkit.WebView/WebKit/...). *Can I use javascript here and invoke function?* You can try it. For more info you can refer to [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android).